# Symfony: how to apply Assert\Valid to each element of an array?

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

I have a complex data-type given by a class `FormatInstance` with a couple properties. Some of them with attributes like `#[Assert\NotBlank]`.

I am using this class in an array in one of my entities like so:

```
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::JSON, nullable: true)]
    #[Assert\All([
        new AssertFormatInstance
    ])]
    private ?array $formatInstances = [];
```

The `AssertFormatInstance`-assertion is meant to validate the interplay of the properties of my `FormatInstance`s but I would also like to run each element of the array through "normal" validation that checks the non-custom assertion-attributes like the aforementioned `Assert\NotBlank` and so on.

But it turns out `Assert\Valid` cannot be nested into `Assert\All` and doing it like this:

```
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::JSON, nullable: true)]
    #[Assert\All([
        new AssertFormatInstance
    ])]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    private ?array $formatInstances = [];
```

doesn't do the trick either.
(EDIT: it actually did the trick but the "real" bug was masking that problem. Still accepted the accepted answer due to the valuable info with regards to collections.)

Is it possible to make this work somehow or do I have to "manually" check everything in my `AssertFormatInstanceValidator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that all element in your `$formatInstances` are type of `FormatInstance`, you can use [Type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html) constraint in your `All` constraint.

Otherwise, I would recommend you to use a `Collection` instead of an `array` and use the `Valid` constraint directly on the property (not in in the `All` constraint). As you can see in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html#traverse), it will validate each object in your collection if the `traverse` option is set to true (which is already true by default).

Comment: Accepting this as an answer for the hint to using a collection and the traverse option.
I gotta say though that actually putting `#[Assert\Valid]` outside the "All" DID do the trick but the "real" problem was masked by another bug in my code.